# getLimit () returns null

Tags: google-drive-android-api

I am developing an app using google drive api.
However, getLimit() may return null from a specific account.
Why does getLimit() return null?

[OAuthGoogleDrive.java:updateAccountInfo:getLimit : null
[OAuthGoogleDrive.java:updateAccountInfo:getUsage : 7592740408804

https://developers.google.com/resources/api-libraries/documentation/drive/v3/java/latest/com/google/api/services/drive/model/About.StorageQuota.html#getLimit--

Answer (score 0):

[Docs says](https://developers.google.com/resources/api-libraries/documentation/drive/v3/java/latest/com/google/api/services/drive/model/About.StorageQuota.html#getLimit--) that it will not always return a valid number, only "**if applicable**".

> The usage limit, **if applicable**. This will not be present if the user
>   has unlimited storage.
>
> Returns: value or **null for none**